# Mixed ANOVA - No effect but interaction

Tags: anova, mixed-model, interaction, interpretation

I was interpreting my SPSS outputs for Mixed- model ANOVA. It says that there is no main effect of gender (my IV)  on time (DV) but there is significant interaction. However the graph does not show any interaction. Gender non-significance p=.560 and interaction - time*gender p=.007 How to understand and report it?

[image: Interactiongraph]

I'd appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should add the output and the graph to your question, otherwise we cannot understand what the problem is

Comment: welcome to the site. You need to give a brief of your problem.